# Attaching/Cloning a submenu to more than one menu item

Tags: python, menu, gtk, submenu

So I have a basic menu structure:

```
menu = gtk.menu()
item1 = gtk.MenuItem('Item 1')
item2 = gtk.MenuItem('Item 2')
menu.append(item1)
menu.append(item2)`
menu.show_all()
```

And I have a submenu:

```
submenu = gtk.menu()
subitem1 = gtk.MenuItem('Option 1')
subitem2 = gtk.MenuItem('Option 2')
submenu.append(subitem1)
submenu.append(subitem2)
submenu.show_all()
```

Now I want to attach this same submenu structure to both of the top level menu items. My first thought was that simply adding `.set_submenu(submenu)` to both `item1` and `item2` should work, but it gives me the error:

```
Gtk-WARNING **: gtk_menu_attach_to_widget(): menu already attached to GtkMenuItem
```

and the submenu only shows up on the last item it was attached to.

In practice I have a lot more than two top level items, and I need to attach the same submenu structure to most of them. So defining the same submenu structure for each item is not really an option. What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: This seems like a weird structure. Why define the same submenu for several items? Just make one menu and decide the item to which it corresponds by looking at which element the user right-clicked :)

Comment: @joaquinlpereyra Uh, no right clicking (just hovering), but I do get the drift. I have done similar stuff in javascript, but I don't know how to do it in python. Any examples?

Comment: Mhmmm, hovering seems like a challenge. Are you able to detect where  is the user hovering? What's the widget below this menu supposed to be?

Comment: @joaquinlpereyra No, I don't. That's why I came up with this structure, but apparently this can't be done without redundancy of code. Also I don't have any specific widget in mind, just a feature I was trying to build while learning gtk menus

Comment: Also, why not create several identical submenus that are different objects with a for or while loop? That seems reasonable too. I'm sure this would work. If you'd like, I could work out some sample code for you :)

Answer (score 0):

As the warning you get on the terminal specifies, you cannot attach the same instance of GtkMenu to different menus — just like you cannot add the same widget to multiple containers.

Your menu hierarchy seems to be overly complex if you find the need to have the same sub-menu in multiple places; it will undoubtedly confuse users, who rely on positional memory to find actions in a hierarchical menu structure.

In any case, if you still want to repeat menus, you can use a simple "menu factory" function, and generate multiple instances from a common GtkBuilder XML description of the menu.